# Why are factors performing better than dummy variables?

Tags: r, decision-tree, gbm, dummy-variable

I am using `gbm.step` from the dismo package (for GBM) in R to construct a boosted regression tree model.  I originally coded categorical variables as factors, however - I was told that coding factors as dummy binary variables (1 for present; 0 for absent), would make it easier for the algorithm to perform the recursive binary splitting.

However, today I ran a bunch of combinations of learning rate, tree complexity, and bag fraction for the data set that contained the factors (320 runs) and the other data set that contain the dummy variables (another 320 runs).

To give a general break down, I had 4 categorical variables.

1) The first categorical had 4 levels - which broke up into four separate 1/0 combinations

2) The second has the same as (1).

3) The third had 3 levels - which broke up into 3 separate 1/0 combinations.

4) The last categorical variable had 2 levels - so 2 1/0 combinations.

After comparing all the runs, the dataset that was coded with factors outperformed the the binary dummy variables every single time (320 times) by 1.5 - 3%, in terms of deviance explained.

I am wondering why, when I would expect the dummy variables to fit the model better?  Does `dismo` automatically create dummy variables behind the scenes?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with `gbm.step` but have you tried using `n-1` 1/0 combinations per factor variable with `n` levels?

Comment: @docendo I guess my problem there is I don't know how to get `n-1` combinations (using `model.matrix`) AND incorporate it into my model.  I am coding my dummy variables in the .csv file and then importing them into R as numeric.  So to answer your question no I have not tried that